# What does it mean to "describe" an event in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This may be too specific of a question, and if so I apologize, but what does my probability textbook mean when it asks that I "describe" events?
Here is the question:
Two dice are thrown, let E be the event that the sum of the rolls is odd and let F be the event that one of the die rolls a 1. 
**describe** the event EF

What does it mean to "describe" that event?  I understand everything, and know how to calculate the probability, I just don't know what the question is asking from me.

Comment: Describe means _tell_ your inquisitor what outcomes are included in the event. This can be in the form of an explicit list such as $EF = \{(1,1), (1,2), (2,1)\}$ or a specification such as $EF = \{(i,j)\colon i+j \leq 3\}$.

Comment: Disagree with the above comment.

Comment: I believe Dilip is correct.

Comment: I'm also suspicious that $EF$ doesn't actually mean anything. Perhaps you meant "E and F" or "E or F" or somesuch?

Comment: If listing outcomes were intended, it would say that: "list the outcomes". Describing means natural language, as in the setup: "E be the event that the sum of the rolls is odd" is the description of an event.

Comment: The notation EF for the intersection of E and F is rather banal. Listing the outcomes in EF when there are not so many seems a good description of EF.

Comment: I've never seen juxtaposition as meaning an intersection of events. Citation?

Comment: First hit of a gg search: Real Analysis and Probability, Robert Ash https://books.google.com/books?id=-YjiBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA445 @DanielR.Collins (and please learn how to use @, thanks in advance.)

Comment: @Did: Clicking your link reports that page 445 is "unavailable for viewing".

Comment: @DanielR.Collins http://i.stack.imgur.com/9wF7K.png